# How to convert a javascript string array to a json string array?

Tags: jquery, json

I'm currently writing a query that needs to send a string array to a webresource through json.
This is the webresource i need to call:

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]

Result API.ImportByNumbers(string[] _Numbers) {}
```

Now i dont know how to form my json data. I've tried sending a normal javascript string array with all the numbers in it, but this gives a

> Could not process child error

When i try an array of objects

```
Data = '{"ID":"1", "ID":"2"}'
```

the value inside webresource is always null...

Can anybody help?

Comment: `Data = '{"ID"="1", "ID"="2"}'` isn't valid JSON.

Comment: try with '{"ID":"1","ID":"2"}'

Comment: sorry my bad, i was allready using ':' instead of '='.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I found the solution:

```
var idArray = ...        array of strings    
var Data = {"_Numbers": idArray }
```

then in in the query:

```
Data = JSON.stringify()
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your webmethod needs `string[] _Numbers` SO you have to pass such a json data which will  send string of number .. Something like this.

var string={"1","2","3"};

```
var jsonData="{"+"_Numbers:"+"'"+string+"'"+"}"
```

Comment: I have also tried that... And the value for _Numbers is always null then.

Comment: $.ajax({
            type: Type,
            url: Url,
            data: Data,
            contentType: ContentType,
            dataType: DataType,
            processdata: ProcessData,
            success: function (msg) {
                debugger;
                alert("import successfull")
            },
            error: ServiceFailed
        });

Comment: All the values should be ok cause im alrdy using them succesfully for a other method.

Comment: Type = "POST";
        Url = "http://...";  
        ContentType = "application/json";
        DataType = "json";
        Data = '{"_Numbers" : "1", "_Numbers" : "2"}'
        varProcessData = true;

Comment: pass the data like i gave you.. mark there is single inverted comma before my string array

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the service is expecting to receive an array, not an object, so you should try not to complicate things and send something like this:

```
var json_str = "[1,2,3]"
```

But if you really need an JSON object, then you should try this

```
var json_str='{"_Numbers":[1,2,3]}'
```

Comment: i have tried both your answers and they don't work:
the first one gives an error back: expected value type and object
so i guess it needs a json object
the 2nd gives an error: expecting '/' found '_', could this be due to the name _Numbers beginning with _?